# Print arrays inside list

Tags: c#

I've created a list, and in that list I've managed to copy an array to, now I want to print the entire list, and I only get the message "System.String[]" since I guess its trying to print the arrays itself and not all the contents inside the arrays.

How can I do this?

```
List<string[]> loggBoken = new List<string[]>();
```

case 1:

```
string[] post = new string[2];
post[0] = Console.Readline()
post[1] = Console.ReadLine();
loggBoken.Add(post.ToArray());
```

Here is the code which is not working:

```
foreach (string[] item in loggBoken) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + item); 
}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you trying to print the values?

Comment: *now I want to print the entire list, and i only get the message*: Okay, but how do you print then?

Comment: The Add() method will only add one item to the list.  Use AddRange() method to add an array to the existing list.

Comment: you have to do one more foreach loop on perticular **System.String[]** that's it

Comment: Alright will do @jdweng

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", loggBoken));`

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several ways:

Two loops:

```
  foreach (string[] line in loggBoken)  {
    foreach(string item in line) {
      Console.Write(item);
      Console.Write('\t');
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
  }
```

One loop, one `Join`:

```
  foreach (string[] line in loggBoken)  
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", line));
```

No loops, two `Join`s (and *Linq*):

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, loggBoken
    .Select(line => string.Join("\t", line))));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original code you get the output:

> "System.String[]"

because `Console.WriteLine` internally calls the `ToString` method (inherited from the `Object` class). This method prints by default the full name of the object-type. In your case it is a `string[]` which is an inhabitant of the namespace `System` thus: `System.String[]`

There is a beautiful method called [String.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to print all elements of a collection in one blow:

```
foreach (string[] item in loggBoken) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", item)); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) And it indeed is beautiful ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
       var loggBoken = new List<string[]>();
        string[] post = new string[2];
        post[0] = "a";
        post[1] = "b";
        loggBoken.Add(post); //don't need to specifie ToArray()

        // use join to create total string of every item in current array
        // split by new line
        foreach (string[] item in loggBoken)
        {                
                MessageBox.Show(String.Join("\n", item));                
        }
```

Comment: Oh, I thought I needed to specify that, now I know, thanks!